# Update multipe apps with almost the same code

Tags: git, github, flutter

My company is using flutter to make several apps with almost identical code. The only difference is the how it looks and some minor differences in functionality.

When doing updates on these apps we are currently doing it manually for each app, but we would like to be able to do these changes only once instead. What would be the best way to achieve this? My only thought was to have all apps in the same GitHub repository, but in different branches, and then do the updates in a master branch to then be able to pull the changes into the other branches. But this does not really seem like the best idea... So if someone else know about something better, I am happy to hear your ideas!

Thanks

Comment: I think you should create your own package (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages)

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, will look into that!

Comment: My company does something similar but we only have a single code base. We wrote a command line tool that swaps out images/themes/etc... based on the app we want. That way we only have a single code base but can produce any number of different versions of the app.